# Yocto meta-virtualization: Could not include required file meta-virt-default-versions.inc

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, virtualization, yocto

I am trying to integrate docker into my yocto image. But after adding my the meta-virtualization and using 
`DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " virtualization meta-virt-default-versions.inc"`

I get the following bitbake error (when trying to build the image or running `bitbake-layers show-layers`):

```
ERROR: Unable to start bitbake server
ERROR: Server log for this session (/home/parallels/Documents/yocto/poky/build/bitbake-cookerdaemon.log):
--- Starting bitbake server pid 21793 at 2019-08-31 21:36:14.688367 ---
ERROR: ParseError at /home/parallels/Documents/yocto/poky/meta-virtualization/conf/layer.conf:41: Could not include required file meta-virt-default-versions.inc
ERROR: ParseError at /home/parallels/Documents/yocto/poky/meta-virtualization/conf/layer.conf:41: Could not include required file meta-virt-default-versions.inc
ERROR: ParseError at /home/parallels/Documents/yocto/poky/meta-virtualization/conf/layer.conf:41: Could not include required file meta-virt-default-versions.inc
```

I am building for `thud - 2.6` and also fetched the thud branch of the meta-virtualization layer. I am building for an intel based board with `MACHINE = "intel-corei7-64"`.

The underlying problem is that if I don't include `DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " virtualization meta-virt-default-versions.inc"` I don't have the right kernel configuration and docker fails to start (CONFIG_IP_VS: missing etc., checked using the docker check-config.sh script)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood some instructions: meta-virt-default-versions.inc is not a DISTRO_FEATURE (but "virtualization" is).

Comment: Your right, I somehow messed this up during testing. With that removed I now get the following error: `ERROR: ParseError at /home/parallels/Documents/yocto/poky/meta-virtualization/conf/layer.conf:41: Could not include required file meta-virt-default-versions.inc`- I can't find this file anywhere in the layer.